# Как вывести все элементы из JSON в PHP?

Tags: php, json

После выполнения следующего кода:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Auth-Email: nh***@gmail.com';
$headers[] = 'X-Auth-Key: 99c22d**741201e77fc9948f1286c9b8';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$event_json = json_decode($result, true);
echo $event_json ["result"]["0"]["id"] . "<br>" ; 
echo $event_json ["result"]["0"]["name"] . "<br>" ;


?>
```

Получаю только по одному id и name:

```
7ca47d86d0f56fe45ad01edb6c4c7771
airbeautty.xyz
```

Как вывести все id и name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$event_json = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($event_json["result"] as $result){
    echo $result['id'];
    echo $result['name'];
}
```

Это должно подойти